# How to renumber files using script?

Tags: bash, shell

How would I renumber files in a directory like "ab0001.xyz" "ab0002.xyz" ... "ab0200.xyz"
to the same numbering but adding a constant (say 97), so "ab0098.xyz" "ab0099.xyz"... "ab0297.xyz"

Also if you could add just a bit of commentary on each function so I don't have to ask again for something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: what is constant is for? Cold you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on several things. For example, if you have always the same names and always are going to have four digit numbers, the solution is somewhat easier. For example:

```
CONSTANT=97
for i in `echo ab*.xyz | sort -r` ; do
   filenumber=`echo $i | tr -dc 0-9`
   numberadd=`expr $filenumber + $CONSTANT`
   mv $i ab`printf "%04d" $numberadd`.xyz
done
```

You've got the `CONSTANT` defined, then you extract just the numbers in the name and use them to sum it with the constant with `expr`. Then, you change the name of the file using `printf` to print just 4 digits filled with zeros.

Comment: This will replace `ab0098.xyz` with the file formerly named `ab0001.xyz`.  You probably need to walk the files in descending order to avoid that.

Comment: You're right. Fortunately, with that name coding, `sort -r` works out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! This work great! And I appreciate the catch, William. Lucky I backed up my data!

Comment: Just tried this with a constant that is greater than 100, and I had problems with it. Anyone know why it doesn't number correctly then?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script. Execute in the same directory where files are located. I'm sure there are more concise solutions...

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
export BASN=ab     # basename
export EXT=xyz     # extension
export CONST=97    # constant to add

for fl in ${BASN}*.${EXT}; do
    noe=${fl%%.${EXT}}   # trim extension
    num=${noe##${BASN}}  # trim basename
    tar=${BASN}`printf '%04d' $((num + ${CONST}))`.${EXT}  # construct target
    mv ${fl} ${tar}
done
```